# What is the underlying algorithm for predicting hidden events using a hidden event language model?

Tags: nlp, hidden-markov-models, srilm

I'm modeling the punctuation prediction problem as arising from a hidden event model, and am trying to follow the algorithm described in Stolcke's paper [Modeling the Prosody of Hidden Events for Improved Word Recognition](http://www.sri.com/sites/default/files/publications/modeling_the_prosody_of_hidden_events.pdf).

After calculating an ngram model, he describes the algorithm for calculating the maximum likelihood sequence of events:

> By using an N-gram model for P(W,S), and decomposing the prosodic likelihoods as in Equation 4, the joint model P(W,S,F)
> becomes equivalent to a hidden Markov
> model (HMM). The HMM states are the (word,event) pairs, while
> prosodic features form the observations. Transition probabilities
> are given by the N-gram model; emission probabilities are estimated by the prosodic model described below.  Based on this
> construction, we can carry out the summation over all possible
> event sequences efficiently  with  the  familiar  forward  dynamic
> programming algorithm for HMMs.

I'm confused how this can be a Markov model with states (word, event) since if our underlying model is an N-gram model, it seems to me that the state needs to encode the N-1 previous words in order to have all necessary information to predict the next state. What's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Table 1, describes the possible hidden labels for a sequence. And 3.2. describes the HMM semantic. So besically, the emissions are words and punctuations. The hidden labels are the labels in the sequence made of the tags proposed in Table 1.

Comment: The confusing aspect is that this still doesn't seem to satisfy the Markov assumption that the transition probability is independent of the preceding sequence after conditioning on the current state. For example, using a 5-gram model on the sentence 'This is a sentence,' the transition probabilities for 'is <comma> a <comma>' is different from the transition probabilities for 'this is a <comma>' even though both share the same current state. (Either just <comma> as you propose, or (a, <comma>) as I initially interpreted). Thanks!